# How can I fill missing value in a particular case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a Dataframe which has two columns 'Key_Skills and 'Job_Title',(both of the column containing few missing values). Now, I want to impute '(Null) Key_Skills' value with the 'Job_Title' column which has filled 'Key_Skills' values.

[image: df]

For example, in column 'Job_Title' at 36th index, there is an 'Accounts Manager' which has a 'Key Skills' value. Now, I want to --

1. Firstly, Impute 'Key Skills' of all the 'Accounts Manager' with the same value(key skills) throughout the dataframe.
2. Secondly, I want to fill 'Key skills' column completely with reference to 'Job Title' value as done in point no. 1 for every row.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i completely understand, but if I am interpreting this correctly the code below should work. What the code below does is group by job title, and if there are any NaN's as a skill set for the same title, it will fill it in. If you wanted to do it specifically for Account Manager, use the ffill and bfill on a filtered dataset only containing Account Manager. You would flip Job title and key skills to do it the other way.

```
 df['Key Skills'] = df.loc[~df['Job Title'].isna()].groupby('Job Title')['Key Skills'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method='bfill'))
```

Comment: This code really make a lot of sense, but while running it, I  got one error as - SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing. Could you tell me what it is about?

Comment: i believe you may need to filter off the NaN's in Job Title first. Try using this code: `df['Key Skills'] = df.loc[~df['Job Title'].isna()].groupby('Job Title')['Key Skills'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method='bfill'))`